# Error: onRoomCreated, status 4? Which error is this? (Android real time multiplayer game)

Tags: android, real-time, google-play-games

i get the following error when I try to connect three participants in a multiplayer game: `Error: onRoomCreated, status 4`. The error occurs sporadic and affects only one player. All devices are virtual maschines.

According to this [Status Codes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes#STATUS_OK) i found out the meaning:

> public static final int STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA
>
> A network error occurred while attempting to retrieve fresh data, and no data was available locally.
>
> Constant Value: 4

Unfortunately the status STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA is not listed at the paragraph onRoomCreated from this [document (onRoomCreated)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomUpdateListener.html#onRoomCreated(int,%20com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room)). That's why I am not sure what is wrong.

Does anybody know which error I actually got?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
    01-29 16:09:04.726: D/dalvikvm(1443): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1303K, 21% free 9449K/11911K, paused 13ms+1ms, total 32ms
01-29 16:09:04.870: W/genymotion_audio(132): out_write() limiting sleep time 46802 to 39909
01-29 16:09:04.882: I/ActivityManager(405): START {cmp=packagename/.MultiplayerActivity (has extras) u=0} from pid 1443
01-29 16:09:04.966: E/SocketStream(389): readFully was waiting for 80688 bytes, got 16192 
01-29 16:09:04.970: E/SocketStream(389): readFully was waiting for 64496 bytes, got 16192 
01-29 16:09:04.982: E/SocketStream(389): readFully was waiting for 48304 bytes, got 5576 
01-29 16:09:05.038: E/SocketStream(389): readFully was waiting for 42728 bytes, got 16192 
01-29 16:09:05.042: E/SocketStream(389): readFully was waiting for 26536 bytes, got 16192 
01-29 16:09:05.046: E/SocketStream(389): readFully was waiting for 10344 bytes, got 5576 
01-29 16:09:05.282: W/PopupManager(1443): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view. Note that this may not work as expected in multi-screen environments
01-29 16:09:05.282: I/System.out(1443): debug onConnected
01-29 16:09:05.338: W/BitmapDrawable(1443): BitmapDrawable cannot decode 
01-29 16:09:05.382: E/WVMExtractor(132): Failed to open libwvm.so
01-29 16:09:05.566: D/ButtonClicker2000(1443): debug Connecting client.
01-29 16:09:05.610: E/WVMExtractor(132): Failed to open libwvm.so
01-29 16:09:05.662: W/GamesServiceBroker(758): Client connected with SDK 7571000, Services 8489070, and Games 35170070
01-29 16:09:05.686: D/ChimeraCfgMgr(758): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games
01-29 16:09:05.686: D/ChimeraModuleLdr(758): Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded
01-29 16:09:05.854: W/EGL_genymotion(1443): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-29 16:09:05.986: V/GLSActivity(620): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
01-29 16:09:06.054: V/GLSActivity(620): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
01-29 16:09:06.226: I/ActivityManager(405): Displayed packagename/.MultiplayerActivity: +1s87ms
01-29 16:09:06.374: V/BaseAuthAsyncOperation(758): All scopes had been granted in the past, skip access token fetching
01-29 16:09:06.694: V/BaseAuthAsyncOperation(758): access token request successful
01-29 16:09:06.890: E/WVMExtractor(132): Failed to open libwvm.so
01-29 16:09:06.998: I/Ads(1443): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
01-29 16:09:07.002: I/Ads(1443): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-29 16:09:07.314: D/ButtonClicker2000(1443): debug onConnected() called. Sign in successful!
01-29 16:09:07.314: D/ButtonClicker2000(1443): debug Sign-in succeeded.
01-29 16:09:08.158: E/WVMExtractor(132): Failed to open libwvm.so
01-29 16:09:08.362: E/WVMExtractor(132): Failed to open libwvm.so
01-29 16:09:08.570: E/WVMExtractor(132): Failed to open libwvm.so
01-29 16:09:08.942: I/Ads(1443): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
01-29 16:09:08.942: I/Ads(1443): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-29 16:09:09.026: E/WVMExtractor(132): Failed to open libwvm.so
01-29 16:09:09.098: D/dalvikvm(620): GC_CONCURRENT freed 902K, 26% free 7789K/10503K, paused 14ms+2ms, total 225ms
01-29 16:09:09.402: I/libjingle(1590): Token type:OAuth2
01-29 16:09:09.402: I/libjingle(1590): Final XMPP server hostname talk.google.com port to 5222
01-29 16:09:09.514: I/libjingle(1590): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
01-29 16:09:09.622: I/libjingle(1590): BeginSSL: talk.google.com
01-29 16:09:09.686: W/libjingle(1590): Warning(openssladapter.cc:388): ContinueSSL -- error -1
01-29 16:09:09.686: W/libjingle(1590): Warning(openssladapter.cc:397): OpenSSLAdapter::Error(ContinueSSL, -1)
01-29 16:09:09.714: I/libjingle(1590): SSL Cleanup
01-29 16:09:09.810: I/libjingle(1590): Token type:OAuth2
01-29 16:09:09.810: I/libjingle(1590): Final XMPP server hostname talk.google.com port to 5222
01-29 16:09:09.902: I/libjingle(1590): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
01-29 16:09:10.022: I/libjingle(1590): BeginSSL: talk.google.com
01-29 16:09:10.094: W/libjingle(1590): Warning(openssladapter.cc:388): ContinueSSL -- error -1
01-29 16:09:10.106: W/libjingle(1590): Warning(openssladapter.cc:397): OpenSSLAdapter::Error(ContinueSSL, -1)
01-29 16:09:10.130: D/ButtonClicker2000(1443): onRoomCreated(4, null)
01-29 16:09:10.130: E/ButtonClicker2000(1443): *** Error: onRoomCreated, status 4
01-29 16:09:10.170: I/libjingle(1590): SSL Cleanup
01-29 16:09:10.186: D/ChimeraCfgMgr(758): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games
01-29 16:09:10.186: D/ChimeraModuleLdr(758): Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded
01-29 16:09:11.270: D/dalvikvm(1443): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1134K, 20% free 9620K/11911K, paused 14ms+1ms, total 42ms
01-29 16:09:17.474: D/dalvikvm(1443): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1413K, 22% free 9607K/12167K, paused 17ms+1ms, total 37ms
01-29 16:09:23.598: D/dalvikvm(1443): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1395K, 21% free 9613K/12167K, paused 14ms+1ms, total 38ms
01-29 16:09:27.954: I/Ads(1443): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
01-29 16:09:27.954: I/Ads(1443): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-29 16:09:29.642: D/dalvikvm(1443): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1409K, 22% free 9605K/12167K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 30ms
01-29 16:09:35.694: D/dalvikvm(1443): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1392K, 21% free 9612K/12167K, paused 14ms+1ms, total 32ms
01-29 16:09:41.806: D/dalvikvm(1443): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1410K, 22% free 9603K/12167K, paused 17ms+0ms, total 32ms
```

Comment: It is worded a little weird, but the onRoomCreated documentation says these are _possible_ status codes, not the entire list.  I think it is safe to use the STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA interpretation indicating some sort of networking issue.

Comment: Thx! I missed the word "possible".

Comment: If the issue is occuring randomly, I think the network connection is just intermittent. As stated also in the documentation that you have provided, It seems like it is a network connection issue and it's best to handle these kinds of error due to it being a possiblity being passed.

Comment: The weird thing is, when i am connecting three emulator devices at the same time, one device is getting the network error and the others not. After waiting 1 min and recreating the room, the broken device is working too.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the Google Play Games version on the emulator.
I updated to the latest version and the error was solved.